# Swing Paint Project - Draw a thicker line with Java

Tags: java

```
package com.ssaurel.swingpaint;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/**
* Component for drawing !
*
* @author sylsau
*
*/
public class DrawArea extends JComponent {

  // Image in which we're going to draw
  private Image image;
  // Graphics2D object ==> used to draw on
  private Graphics2D g2;
  // Mouse coordinates
  private int currentX, currentY, oldX, oldY;

  public DrawArea() {
    setDoubleBuffered(false);
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // save coord x,y when mouse is pressed
        oldX = e.getX();
        oldY = e.getY();
      }
    });

    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        // coord x,y when drag mouse
        currentX = e.getX();
        currentY = e.getY();

        if (g2 != null) {
          // draw line if g2 context not null
          g2.drawLine(oldX, oldY, currentX, currentY);
          // refresh draw area to repaint
          repaint();
          // store current coords x,y as olds x,y
          oldX = currentX;
          oldY = currentY;
        }
      }
    });
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (image == null) {
      // image to draw null ==> we create
      image = createImage(getSize().width, getSize().height);
      g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
      // enable antialiasing
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      // clear draw area
      clear();
    }

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
  }

  // now we create exposed methods
  public void clear() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.white);
    // draw white on entire draw area to clear
    g2.fillRect(0, 0, getSize().width, getSize().height);
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
    repaint();
  }

  public void red() {
    // apply red color on g2 context
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
  }

  public void black() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.black);
  }

  public void magenta() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.magenta);
  }

  public void green() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.green);
  }

  public void blue() {
    g2.setPaint(Color.blue);
  }

}

package com.ssaurel.swingpaint;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingPaint {

  JButton clearBtn, markerBtn, blackBtn, blueBtn, greenBtn, redBtn, magentaBtn;
  DrawArea drawArea;
  ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == clearBtn) {
        drawArea.clear();
      } else if (e.getSource() == blackBtn) {
        drawArea.black();
      } else if (e.getSource() == blueBtn) {
        drawArea.blue();
      } else if (e.getSource() == greenBtn) {
        drawArea.green();
      } else if (e.getSource() == markerBtn) {
        drawArea.black(); 
      } else if (e.getSource() == redBtn) {
        drawArea.red();
      } else if (e.getSource() == magentaBtn) {
        drawArea.magenta();
      }
    }
  };

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SwingPaint().show();
  }

  public void show() {



    // create main frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Paint");
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    // set layout on content pane
    content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // create draw area
    drawArea = new DrawArea();

    // add to content pane
    content.add(drawArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // create controls to apply colors and call clear feature
    JPanel controls = new JPanel();

    clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");
    clearBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    blackBtn = new JButton("Black");
    blackBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    blueBtn = new JButton("Blue");
    blueBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    greenBtn = new JButton("Green");
    greenBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    redBtn = new JButton("Red");
    redBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    magentaBtn = new JButton("Magenta");
    magentaBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    markerBtn = new JButton("Marker");
    markerBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);

    // add to panel
    controls.add(markerBtn);
    controls.add(greenBtn);
    controls.add(blueBtn);
    controls.add(blackBtn);
    controls.add(redBtn);
    controls.add(magentaBtn);
    controls.add(clearBtn);

    // add to content pane
    content.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    frame.setSize(900, 720);
    // can close frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // show the swing paint result
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

the code here explains a drawing tool running on a java language using netbeans. what I would like is that the "Marker" to be thicker than default. It's thin to draw this way. well at least for me. anyways, I am lost on how to make it thicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Is not a good answer anymore because the op changed his post!)

You need to change your font.

So you need to call on your swing component

```
.setFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
```

Or go with

```
.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.BOLD,  16))
```

To set a new font

Comment: It is not a font, it's drawing pencil and it's only set to default small thickness... I was wondering if you can bold the default thickness.

Comment: what do I have to import?

Comment: I can not answer that because you provided to less code and to less information about what you really try to accomplish

Comment: And yes you can bold the thickness by multiplying the fontsize by a defined factor

Comment: You need to call setFont() on your g2 object in the DrawArea class. That will work.

Comment: I did that but I get an import error, I imported the font package and still didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have edited the post to explain that you want your lines to be drawn thicker (which is not the same as 'bold' - bold applies only to fonts) you need to look up Java "stroke styles".

Here is the official [filling and stroking tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html). There are plenty of others.